# laravel eloquent: filtering rows with month or date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im trying to represent some data based on months or dates. Lets consider the following code in my blade.

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
   <tr>
     <td> {{ $course->course_title }} </td>
     <td> {{ $course->revenue->sum('profit') }} BDT</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

this block of code gives me the sum of profit column from all rows. I have a timestamps field in my table. Now i want to show the sum of profit made on month january/february. In short sum the profit made on january. how do i do that?

Comment: have you tried with group by/having?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP BY`.

`$query->groupBy(DB::raw('GROUP BY YEAR(your_date_field), MONTH(your_date_field)'));`

But this way, you won't be able to do `sum` after your query, since that a single row will exist for every month, so we need to add the `sum` aggregate to your query:

`$query->select(DB::raw('sum(profit) as month_profit'));`

Now your results will have a column `month_profit` for each month row.